# visual studio msql server

Tags: c#, sql

У меня в код sqlconnection = new sqlconnection(@"Data Source...)
При опубликовании приложении и переносе его на другой компьютер, нужно будет в ручную создавать БД на другом компьютере?

Comment: Ну сама собой из ниоткуда база же не возмется, верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если использовать EntityFrameworkCore, то у инстанса контекста базы данных `DbContext` есть свойство `Database` с методом [`EnsureCreated()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-7.0), который делает следующее:

> - Если база данных существует и содержит таблицы, никакие действия не предпринимаются. Для обеспечения совместимости схемы базы данных с
>   моделью Entity Framework ничего не делается.
> - Если база данных существует, но не содержит таблиц, то для создания схемы базы данных используется модель Entity Framework.
> - Если база данных не существует, создается база данных, а для создания схемы базы данных используется модель Entity Framework.

Пример:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // описание модели

    public ApplicationContext() => Database.EnsureCreated();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(/* строка подключения */);
    }
}
```

В старых версиях EF для полного .NET Framework тоже есть подобный метод [`CreateIfNotExists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.createifnotexists?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Пример:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // описание модели

    public MyDbContext ()
        :base(/* строка подключения */)
    {
       Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если кому интересно, я в строку SqlConnection, добавил имя компьютера через Environment.MachineName; И добавил чтение скрипта на создание БД, если БД не подключается(так как её нет). так что на новом должно работать.